# Does Angular understand a relational model?

Tags: angularjs

I am just beginning to read about Angular. I understand that Angular, when dealing with an `ng-repeat` binding, expects a *nested* model, such as:

```
    var model =  {

          states:
             [ 
              { state: "NY", cities: ["NYC", "Albany", "Schenectady"] },
              { state: "PA", cities: ["Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", "Scranton"]}
             ] 
    }
```

EDIT: to produce this:

```
           <ul>NY
             <li>NYC</li>
             <li>Albany</li>
             <li>Schenectady</li>
           </ul>
           <ul>PA
             <li>Philadelphia</li>
             <li>Pittsburgh</li>
             <li>Scranton</li>
           </ul>
```

But does Angular also understand how to use a *relational* model like this for `ng-repeat` bindings?

```
    var model = {

          states: [ {state:"NY"}, {state: "PA"}],
          cities: [ 
                   {state: "NY", city: "NYC"}, 
                   {state: "NY", city: "Albany"}, 
                   {state: "NY", city: "Schenectady"},
                   {state: "PA", city: "Philadelphia"},
                   {state: "PA", city: "Pittsburgh"},
                   {state: "PA", city: "Scranton"}
                   ]
           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve the same behaviour using filters when you have a relational model.

First scenario:

```
var model =  {

      states:
         [ 
          { state: "NY", cities: ["NYC", "Albany", "Schenectady"] },
          { state: "PA", cities: ["Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", "Scranton"]}
         ] 
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul ng-repeat="state in model.states">
  {{state}} 
  <li ng-repeat="city in state.cities">{{city}}</li>
</ul>
```

Second scenario:

```
var model = {

      states: [ {state:"NY"}, {state: "PA"}],
      cities: [ 
               {state: "NY", city: "NYC"}, 
               {state: "NY", city: "Albany"}, 
               {state: "NY", city: "Schenectady"},
               {state: "PA", city: "Philadelphia"},
               {state: "PA", city: "Pittsburgh"},
               {state: "PA", city: "Scranton"}
               ]
       }
```

HTML

```
<ul ng-repeat="state in states">
 {{state}}
 <li ng-repeat="city in cities | filter:{state: state}">{{city.city}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in model">...</div>
```

This might be what you're trying to achieve. The contents of the div can now reference `{{ key }}` and `{{ value }}` for each property of the object.